# Seaborn: Plot a Barplot showing the Mean of an Attribute on the Y Axis?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I am new to Seaborn, and I am trying to plot a `barplot` that shows the **average (mean)** of an attribute on the Y axis, but I am unsure what is going wrong with my code.

This is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Day', y=df['Spending'].mean())
ax.set(xlabel="Day of the Week", ylabel = "Average Spending each Day")
```

When I try to execute my code, I just get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Any help on how to get the average to show on my Y axis would be greatly appreciated, including what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default,

```
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Day', y='Spending')
```

shows the mean of `Spending` on the `y` axis.